# is it possible to define more vehicle data items from Vehicle APIs in Fleetboard?

Tags: fleetboard

The Vehicle API is based on the listener pattern for the Fleetboard. there are limited Vehicle data items from Vehicle APIs like :

- Accelerator Pedal Position
- Ambient Temperature
- Brake Pedal
- Clutch Pedal
- Coolant Temperature
- Cruise Control
- Current Fuel Consumption
- Driver ID
- Engine Speed
- FMS standard version number
- Fuel Level
- Power Takeoff State
- Service Distance
- Total Engine Hours
- Total Fuel
- Total Vehicle Distance
- Vehicle Identification Number
- Vehicle Speed
- Vehicle Weight

What are the possibilities to get other vehicle data items from APIs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the existing API will extended in the future but currently the documented values are the only ones that are available.
There is no possibility to directly access vehicle data that is not available in the APIs.

Comment: do you have any idea about fleetboard connection with truck CANbus ? Fleetboard is directly connected to CANbus or OBD II with extra module.because Tomtom hardware  is always connected with Link 100 for vehicle data transmission. but Fleetboard Dock has two extra plug.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get more vehicle data. The API is the only way to get data from the vehicle.

best regards

Comment: do you have any idea about fleetboard connection with truck CANbus ? Fleetboard is directly connected to CANbus or OBD II with extra module.

Comment: The device is connected to an internal ECU, not to the CAN directly.

Comment: I am not able to activate developer option from fleetboard....also I tried with "adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS ". but i am getting error:error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.

Comment: Did you receive a developer device? Or a usual customer device? Can you see the "developer" banner at the top right corner?